# Charset problem in .htaccess while using Chinese, Japanese, Turkish, Russian

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, character-encoding

My .htaccess works perfect on live server but shows 500 error when setup on local machine. If I remove Chinese, Japanese, Turkish, Russian rules from it it works perfect but it necessary to have those charters in it.

**Example:**

```
RewriteRule ^会員専用サイト\/今すぐ登録.php /JP/members/join_now.php?rw=$0&lang=JP&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^Члены\/Регистрация.php /RU/members/join_now.php?rw=$0&lang=RU&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^üye\/Kayıt-ol.php  /TR/members/join_now.php?rw=$0&lang=TR&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^멤버구역\/가입.php    /KR/members/join_now.php?rw=$0&lang=KR&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

also used chartset to UTF-8 in htaccess but no success

---

Local machine using WAMP

OS: Windows XP, Windows 7

Comment: Works absolutely fine on Apache 2.2.17 VC9 build on Windows XP SP2 ENG.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it successfully on a Debian 6.0 machine + windows7 wamp. So it should be working. 
Of course you need to make sure your files are well encoded and apache can handle them.

For wamp: open the `httpd.conf` file from the notification icon. Notepad should pop-up. 
Save the file as : select `UTF-8` and filter `*.*`

Please make sure that the file is saved as `httpd.conf` and not `httpd.conf.txt`

Add the rules.

Restart the services. Should work.

#### FYI

Tested on Debian 6.0:

```
RewriteRule ^会員専$ /stack/redirect.php [L,R]
```

Is working fine for me. Here is the log:

```
 strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/会員専 -> 会員専
 applying pattern '^会員専$' to uri '会員専'
 rewrite '会員専' -> '/stack/redirect.php'
 explicitly forcing redirect with http://mysite.org/stack/redirect.php
 escaping http://mysite.org/stack/redirect.php for redirect
 redirect to http://mysite.org/stack/redirect.php [REDIRECT/302]
 strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/stack/redirect.php -> stack/redirect.php
 applying pattern '^会員専$' to uri 'stack/redirect.php'
 pass through /var/www/stack/redirect.php
```